# How to apply google spreadsheet arrayformula for picking out the earliest date in a mixed set of values?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, array-formulas

I need to somehow cross data from 2 columns with different criteria: in the first one I have worker's id, in the other - their dates of activities. The idea is to  display the earliest date for a selected worker. I tried to organize it via SUMIFS but it only shows one correct date for a worker which started on the absolutely earliest date from the whole range. 
See my sample spreadsheet with those formulas here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1somY2LxNpQic1vclubw-DV9h0Jo3lqcwUuqrI-Praw0/edit?usp=sharing

In other words I'm looking for a formula that will sort out only dates of an appropriate (chosen) worker and display the minimal (earliest) date from it.

Comment: Don't post examples of the problem on other sites. All information about your question should be in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=query(A1:B8; "select A, min(B) group by A";1)
```

See also cell G1 in the spreadsheet you shared.

Alternatively, try:

```
=vlookup(D2; sort(A2:B8; 2;1); 2; 0)
```

Comment: Note also when you change worker in cell D2, it doesn't display correct date in the E2 (as it meant to). It only works with worker 1 as he started to work on the minimal date in the range...

Comment: My formula gave the 'starting' date for all the workers at once. But if you want to have a separate column with all the workers and then look up that date, then see my updated answer.

Comment: Magic! Works exactly as it should;) Thx for pointing out the right direction with vlookup!